# cf push not updating Git Repository on IBM BlueMix

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

After I do a `cf push` of my code changes, done locally, I am not seeing the changes in the Git Repository on Bluemix when I click on the "Edit code" in the Overview section. It still shows the Starter application code that IBM originally created.  What is odd is that, when I launch my route URL, I do in fact see the changes I pushed.

So in a nutshell, `cf push` seems to update the run time environment and changes are all visible, when I access my URL, but it is not updating the code in the Git Repository. Do I need to perform any other operations on my local machine, after I do `cf push`?  If so, can you please provide me an example of the needed commands that I need to execute locally.

Comment: I do not think `cf` CLI will perform any changes to git.`cf push` just pushes your application binaries

Answer (score 1):

By pushing by the `cf` tool you bypass the jazz git repository. What you can do to fix that is clone the repo, update the git project locally with your actual project, and push the changes.

- `git clone` your jazz repository locally
- delete all files but the `.git`directory in the newly created directory
- copy all files from your project in this same directory
- create a .gitignore (https://www.gitignore.io/)
- `git add .`
- `git commit "Initial commit"`
- `git push`

By default, the DevOps pipeline will automatically build & deploy your changes, so after a few minutes you'll have your app running again, but this time it will be in sync with the repository.

If you use the git repository, you shouldn't use `cf push` anymore.